# Find and replace expression in a string with HTML tags

Tags: javascript

This is a follow up question of [Replace HTML tag with string that contains tag attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69789989/replace-html-tag-with-string-that-contains-tag-attribute).

This time I would like to do the opposite process and replace occurrences of `${something.foo.bar}` back to `<input type="button" disabled="" data-value="something.foo.bar" value="foo.bar" />`.
For example consider this string:

```
"the quick ${something.brown.fox} jumps over the ${something.lazy.dog}"
```

The end result should be:

```
the quick <input type="button" disabled="" data-value="something.brown.fox" value="brown.fox" /> jumps over the <input type="button" disabled="" data-value="something.lazy.dog" value="lazy.dog" />
```

Note that `something.` is a known prefix and will always be present inside the curly braces, so the input `data-value` should be the value between the braces and the input `value` attribute should contain the value without the prefix.

I've tried to solve it with multiple chaining of Regex `match` and `replaceAll` but didn't managed to get the desired outcome.

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it simply using [String.replace](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace):

```js
const s = "the quick ${something.brown.fox} jumps over the ${something.lazy.dog}"
const res = s.replace(/\$\{([^}]+)\}/g, (x, y) => {
  const [prefix, ...rest] = y.split('.')
  return `<input type="button" disabled="" data-value="${y}" value="${rest.join('.')}" />`
})

console.log(res)
```

Comment: Thanks! totally forgot that `replace` could take callback function.